Same data, same Conda environment - different plots?
I made some nice plots of some data I have on my machine. I tried to set up the same thing on a friends machine - made the Conda environment with exactly the same packages as my environment, same Python version, same Visual Studio, same code that I pulled from my GitHub... and the plot on her machine looks awful. I checked our matplotlibrc files, and they are (as far as I can tell) the same.
The only differences I can tell is the the Conda and Python versions we have have installed. I have in my base and specific conda env:
conda --version = 24.1.2
 python -- version = 3.12.3
and in hers:
(base) conda --version = 4.8.2
(base) python --version = 3.7.6
(base) conda --version = 4.8.2
(base) python --version = 3.12.3
So the same version of Conda, but different versions of Python. We tried updating both Anaconda and Python, but somehow it just didn't work. We will try to uninstall and reinstall Anaconda, but what else can I try? Might the Anaconda distribution affect the plotting, even if the versions are the same?
For context, it looks like this: Same Matplotlib code produces different images on different machines like one plot really nice, the other all bunched up and weird. I tried the stuff suggested in the comments there, like checking the backend with matplotlib.get_backend(), which gave the same on both machines.
I also tried making some dummy random data and plotting it, and it works fine.
Here is a minimally reproducible example gives nice results on my machine, and not nice ones on my friends machine:
ds_west= pd.read_csv(f"{directory}VEI_X5733_240422183946_WEST_compensated.txt", sep="\t") 
ds_west = ds_west.drop(index=np.r_[0:10, 314:325]) 
max_pressure_index = ds_west['Pressure'].idxmax()

west_surface_down = ds_west.iloc[:max_pressure_index]
west_bottom_up= ds_west.iloc[max_pressure_index:]

plt.scatter(west_bottom_up['Temperature'], west_bottom_up['Pressure'])

So its reading a txt file with pandas csv. This code gives me this:

and this same code gives this on her machine: 
So you can see if you look closely that the values are kind of right but why so bunched up? And why is the shape of the figure completely wrong?

The second plot has classic signs that the values are strings, not numeric.

The resolution is low, but it looks to me like commas are being used as the decimal point. If so, it needs decimal=',' when reading the csv or else the values become strings and are plotted as categorical variables.

And FYI, the post you linked isn't related. Their confusion matrix got bunched up simply because the 1028x715 figure was too small to fit all those characters.

I should think you could Dockerise this project, and then on two machines the versions of all software would be identical. Build the image on one computer and then pull the image over to the other.

Is it possible that you have different LANG environments on the two machines? In one the decimal separator is "," and all is well, in the other it's "." and, say, "30,14xxxx" is then interpreted as a string? (NB This is hypothetical and cannot be posted as an answer)
